# Will Dawn dishwater and bleach get rid of cutworms without killing my flowers?

Tags: flowers, pest-control, pests

Cutworms are killing all of my flowers. I'm trying to get rid of them. I'm thinking about using Dawn dishwater and a small amount of bleach, but will that kill my plants?

Comment: Welcome Wendy! I re-worded your title and question a bit to make it a little bit longer. If that's not what you meant, please change it back! Our system is a bit different from others, so why don't you take a look around our [help]? [Ask] is a good place to start. I see you already got a great answer!  We hope you stay and have fun with us!

Answer (score 2):

Cutworms live at or near the base of the plants they are eating.  Soap and bleach are not terribly effective on them as they are in the soil.

What works really well is diatomaceous earth around the base of the plant.  Repeat every few days.

Or you can take a trowel and work the soil around the base of the plants and pop any suspects into some soap and water.